# Return well-formed numbers

Tags: algorithm, performance, python

I found this in an interview questions forum:

> Write a function to return well formed
>   numbers of size n. A well formed
>   number is one in which digit i is less
>   than digit i+1, for example 123, 246, 349 etc

So here's how I would do it in Python:

> - input number of digits (x)
> - loop over all the numbers of x digits
> - for each number n, if str(n) == "".join(sorted(str(n))), print number

So my question is... Is this method efficient and pythonic? I'm sure there should be a more elegant way out there, so any tips would be great appreciated.

Craig

Comment: BTW, I consider this a very poor interview question.

Comment: Any given algorithm can be implemented in an Pythonic or not-Pythonic  way. Why don't you have a crack at implementing it and post that in your question?

Answer (score 7):

How about this solution?

```
[int("".join(x)) for x in itertools.combinations("123456789", n)]
```

Comment: Cute, `itertools.combinations` returns them in canonical order. Was about to discover this answer myself. =)

Comment: Extremely inefficient to create ALL combinations and then still having to check if the numbers are well formed. But then the worst case is n = 9; so all combinations up to length n would be 2^9-1; that's quite tame.

Comment: @Voo: The above code produces exactly the required numbers.  You don't need any additional check.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you've already lost if you're checking every number.

I'd implement this with a stack. Start by putting 1-9 on the stack. When you take a number off of the stack, add another number to it if you can following those rules. If it's n digits, then print it. If it's not n digits, put it back on the stack.

Let's say you grab 7 from the stack. 8 and 9 are the only numbers bigger than 7, so in o(1) time you can put 78 and 79 on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation doesn't ensure either the number of digits, or the *strictly less than* part of the well-formedness requirement.

---

Anyway, here's an efficient way to produce the sequence without any library functions (conversion to python is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
void find_well_formed(char* pfirst, char* pnext, int min, int slack, int digits_left)
{
    if (!digits_left) puts(pfirst);
    else for( int i = 0; i <= slack; ++i )
        find_well_formed(pfirst, pnext+1, (*pnext=min+i)+1, slack - i, digits_left-1);
}

char* result = malloc(n+2);
result[n] = '\n';
find_well_formed(&result[0], &result[0], '1', 9-n, n);
free(result);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/0oZAV

If python is requiring more code to solve this than C++, something's wrong.

Comment: loop over all numbers of digit (x) - I actually meant loop over all numbers of x digits. The question does not explicitly mention strictly less than so I assume <= is fine

Comment: @Craig: "less than" means `<`.  And `1000` has four digits, but after you sort them, the number is `1` which has only one digit.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are trying to return well formed numbers 'up to' n digits in your approach, that is probably not the thing they were asking for

2) Sorting each number in that range is a bit silly. You may check whether each number is a well formed one by comparing the consecutive digits, which will take `O(d)` time for each number. However, sorting will definitely take more than that.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to follow the logic:

- For a given number, the digits we can add to the beginning of it and still get a well-formed number are all less than the minimum digit in the number
- For a given well-formed number, the minimum digit is always the first digit
- The maximum number of digits we can add to a given number and keep it well-formed is equal to it's (minimum digit - 1)

Given the above, the following could be used to solve the problem:

```
def _well_formed_numbers(current_number_str, size):
    if size == 0: 
        # we don't need to add any more
        return [current_number_str]
    if(len(current_number_str) == 0):
        min_digit = 9
    else:
        min_digit = int(current_number_str[0]) - 1
    if min_digit < size: 
        raise Exception("can't add " + str(size) + " more digits to " + current_number_str)
    # Return a list of all the numbers resulting from recursively applying 
    # this function to the "children" of the number we already have
    # Children are the input number with one valid digit added to the beginning
    # valid digits are [size .. min_digit], inclusive
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [_well_formed_numbers(str(digit) + str(current_number_str), size-1) for digit in range(size,min_digit+1)])

def well_formed_numbers(size):
    if size <= 0 or size >= 10:
        raise "invalid size for perfect number: " + str(size)
    return _well_formed_numbers("", size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
        def testMaxList(self):
            self.assertEqual(["123456789"], well_formed_numbers(9))

        def testEightList(self):
            self.assertEqual(sorted(['12345678', '12345679', '12345689', '12345789', '12346789', '12356789', '12456789', '13456789', '23456789']), sorted(well_formed_numbers(8)))

        def testOneList(self):
            self.assertEqual(sorted(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]), sorted(well_formed_numbers(1)))

        def testTwoList(self):
            self.assertEqual(sorted(['12', '13', '23', '14', '24', '34', '15', '25', '35', '45', '16', '26', '36', '46', '56', '17', '27', '37', '47', '57', '67', '18', '28', '38', '48', '58', '68', '78', '19', '29', '39', '49', '59', '69', '79', '89']), sorted(well_formed_numbers(2)))

    unittest.main()
```

Admittedly, Sven Marnach's answer is shorter and cleverer... but this one shows the thought process of a reasonable algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following:

the maximal value of the i-th digit is max[i] = 10 - (len - i)

- start with 1..n
- on each step, find the leftmost position i where digit[i] == max[i]
- if no such i is found, increase the rightmost digit
- if i is found, and it is = 0, we're done
- if i is found, and it is > 0, increase digit[i - 1] and fill the rest so that digit[j] = digit[j - 1] + 1

in (the intentionally ugly) python

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
n = len(a)

while 1:
    print a
    f = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] == 10 - (n - i):
            if i == 0:
                exit()
            else:
                f = 1
                a[i - 1] += 1
                for j in range(i, n):
                    a[j] = a[j - 1] + 1
                break

    if f == 0:
        a[n - 1] += 1
```